# SSRS Uploaded report only shows xml when viewed

Tags: xml, reporting-services, rdlc

I have uploaded a report (rdlc) and I can view it when I navigate to report manager url, but when I click on the report, all I get is the xml and no report view.

I am using SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services.

Comment: RDL and RDLC (client and to be used within an RDLC viewer control) is not a file extension like HTML.  The report has to be added to the reporting server.  Within the reporting server context, Microsoft makes sure that you cannot do things like update a database from your report, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**rdlc** files are client-side reports and are deployed with an application and processed by the application.

Report Server server-side reports, i.e. **rdl** files, are processed on an SSRS Report Server.

These are totally different file types - the Report Server (exposed through the Report Manager website) expects an **rdl** file, not **rdlc**, which is why it's just displaying the **rdlc** definition only and not an actual report.

You need to develop a server-side report (i.e. **rdl**) and deploy this if you want to view it through a Report Server.

See [Creating Client Report Definition (.rdlc) Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252067.aspx) and [Reporting Services Reports (SSRS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522712.aspx) - those links might help explain the difference in more detail.